# How to insert/update a separate row for each column with SQLServer

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I'm trying to import data from one table to another via a stored procedure. I need to be able to do both inserts and updates. I have the inserts figured out. Now, I'm trying to find the most elegant way to do the updates.

This is a table like the one I am trying to pull data from. Forgive any mistakes in the table creation scripts. They are just examples.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[source_table](
    [linkage_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [code] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_1] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_2] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_3] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_4] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_5] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_6] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_7] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_8] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_9] [char](6) NULL,
    [code_10] [char](6) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to insert into a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[destination_table](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [linkage_id] [int] NULL,
    [code] [char](30) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_destination_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When records are pulled from the source_table, a row needs to be inserted into the destination table for each code with a value entered on the source table. You might end up with values like this in the destination table:

```
id | linkage_id | code
______________________
1  | 501        | abc
2  | 501        | abb
3  | 501        | aba
4  | 502        | aaa
5  | 503        | aaa
6  | 503        | aab
7  | 503        | abc
8  | 503        | bba
9  | 503        | cc
```

Then, I might need to update the destination table with new values from the source table:

```
linkage_id | code | code_1 | code_2 | code_3 | code_4 | ...
______________________
501        | ccc  | abb    | bbb    |        |        | ...
```

I need the records to be updated in the correct order. My goal is for the destination table to look like this when I am done:

```
id | linkage_id | code
______________________
1  | 501        | ccc
2  | 501        | abb
3  | 501        | bbb
4  | 502        | aaa
5  | 503        | aaa
6  | 503        | aab
7  | 503        | abc
8  | 503        | bba
9  | 503        | cc
```

My guess is that there will be cursors involved... Anyone have any neat ideas?

One option that just occurred to me is that instead of trying to update the records in the destination_table, I could delete all of the previous records and reinsert them.

Comment: Can you show an example of actual data in source table? I'm not sure where the update comes into it.

Comment: I can't show you actual data, but above (the second table in the original post) is an example of what the data would look like in the source table. In the above example, we would be trying to update each record in the destination_table with a linkage_id of 501.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) and [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
-- Optional table variable to assist with processing source data into destination table. 
-- Holds the normalized form of the data in source_table
declare @p table(linkage_id int, code nchar(6))

-- UNPIVOT the data from columns into rows to be able to use MERGE
insert into @p (linkage_id, code)
select linkage_id, value
from (select linkage_id, code, code_1, code_2 from source_table) s
unpivot (
    value for [key] in (code, code_1, code_2)
) as PivotTable

-- Check out the data by eye
-- select * from @p

-- Now we can update the destination table from the normalized source values
merge destination_table as d
    using (select linkage_id, code from @p) as source (linkage_id, code)
    on d.linkage_id = source.linkage_id
when matched
    then update set d.code = source.code
when not matched
    then insert (linkage_id, code) values (source.linkage_id, source.code);
```